# Alphabet character prints wrong ISO code

Tags: c

So, i have this simple code,

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int main()
    {
        char c;
        c = getchar();
        printf("%d",c);
        return 0;
    }
```

Now let's say c = 'α' - a in greek alphabet. According to ISO8859-7 , the program should print 225,but instead it prints -31. 
Does anybody know what causes this mistake?

Comment: `char c;` is signed on your system. Just use `unsigned char c`

Comment: `getchar` returns `int` for a reason. Why not just use `int c;`?

Comment: @jean-françois: `getchar` returns an `int`

Comment: I know that. But unsigned char also works (and consumes less memory :))

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre `unsigned char` does *not* work if you're interested in detecting `EOF`.

Comment: @SteveSummit of course. unsigned char is a bad idea in general. I tend to forget about this whole EOF thing.

Answer (score 2):

`getchar()` and friends return an `int` with a *value* in the `unsigned char` range or `EOF`.  `EOF` is a negative value. [@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48725587/alphabet-character-prints-wrong-iso-code/48725742#comment84450192_48725587)

Use `int`.

```
int main() {
    // char c;
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    printf("%d\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

---

> Does anybody know what causes this mistake?

`getchar()` returned a value of 225, yet code assigned that to a `char`, which is *signed* on OP's platform with a range of -128 to 127. This invokes *implementation defined behavior*.

> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an implementation-defined signal is raised.  C11dr §6.3.1.3 3

A common *implementation defined behavior* is to decrease the value by 256 to `-31`.  Other results are possible.

Answer (score 1):

Because `char c;` is signed on your system.

`getchar` returns an integer, which overflows your `char`:  `225-256 = -31`

Just use `unsigned char c;` instead, or more simply `int`, which consumes slightly more memory (shouldn't be an issue) but is able to distinguish `EOF` from `255`. Go for `int`: it's simple and noone will wonder about that.

Comment: "Consumes more memory"? Oh crap, 3 more bytes? That's almost 0.00000002% of the RAM on this machine. :-)

Comment: depending on compilers you can get 8-byte ints and 0.00000004% of the RAM. That's how bloated programs start :) but you're right.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer to the question, but I want to address (pun intended) the increased memory usage of an `int` vs. a `char` variable as discussed in other comments and answers, and a bit of code formatting will help with this.

When you're talking about memory use, the best policy is to be prepared for surprises.

A local variable like the one in the question will often occupy *zero* bytes of memory regardless of its size, if it is stored in a register instead of memory. However, it may take more *code* to convert the data width, as is the case here.

For comparison, here is the compiled code from VS2017 in x86 release mode, first with an `int` variable:

```
                     int c;
                     c = getchar();
FF 15 B0 20 40 00    call        dword ptr [__imp__getchar (04020B0h)]  
                     printf("%d",c);
50                   push        eax  
68 F8 20 40 00       push        offset string "%d" (04020F8h)  
E8 1F 00 00 00       call        printf (0401030h)  
83 C4 08             add         esp,8
```

And with a `char`:

```
                     char c;
                     c = getchar();
FF 15 B0 20 40 00    call        dword ptr [__imp__getchar (04020B0h)]  
                     printf("%d",c);
0F BE C0             movsx       eax,al  ;; Widen 'char' to 'int'
50                   push        eax  
68 F8 20 40 00       push        offset string "%d" (04020F8h)  
E8 1C 00 00 00       call        printf (0401030h)  
83 C4 08             add         esp,8
```

The generated code is identical, except that the `char` version has an extra three-byte instruction, the `movsx eax, al` to widen the `char` to an `int` before pushing it. So instead of saving memory, the `char` used three more bytes of code.

Of course in a simple test like this, you don't care how much code or data memory is used - in fact you may not ever do an optimized build at all, only a debug build.

And things may well change in a more complex piece of code. For example, if you have an *array* of `char` vs. `int`, obviously the array will take more memory for the `int` values, assuming it isn't a very small array that ends up in registers.

Even for data that does end up in registers, a shorter data type may help because it lets more data get packed into the registers (e.g. by using things like the `bl` and `bh` registers for byte values), so less data spills out into actual memory.

But you really don't know until you look at the size of the generated code and how it uses memory.

In any case, this is all a moot point for the code in the question, since it just isn't correct to use a `char` or `unsigned char` as the return value for `getchar()`. But it is interesting to look at what kind of code gets generated for the different data types.